# MongoDB Compass - Proxy Settings

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, mongodb-compass

I want to display my geo-locations on a map but Compass needs access to the internet to load the map. Because of this external connection, I need to change the proxy settings of the program.

I couldn't find any information on this in the [documentation](https://docs.mongodb.com/compass/current). I also tried the Beta instead of the Stable version but both seem to not offer changing proxy settings in the GUI.

Is there any way to add proxy settings to MongoDB Compass?

Comment: I am thinking the same. Did you find any solution?

Comment: @Anand I am afraid we stopped using Compass at some point in time. Until then, this feature was not added. I do not have any more information, sorry

Comment: Thanks. I think it is still not in GUI. I have added it using their shell.

Answer (score -6):

You need to make sure that geo visualizations are turned on. Go to Help->Privacy Settings and make sure Geo Viz is enabled.

Once you have done that, you also need to make sure that your data is stored in the correct format. E.g.:

{
   location: {
      type: "Point",
      coordinates: [-73.856077, 40.848447]
   },
   name: "Morris Park Bake Shop"
}

Once you have that, maps should be displayed (and are interactive by clicking or shift+click on them).

Comment: https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/COMPASS-1864   A Jira Request for having proxy configuration in MongoDB Compass is still open since 2017 ! Don't know when it will be or whether it will be addressed!